# Have, had, and Have had

Tags: grammar

Does the following sentence have a different meanings?

I **have** a lot of tasks this week.

I **had** a lot of tasks this week.

I **have had** a lot of task this week.

Comment: You forgot "had had".

Comment: (And it should be "tasks" in the third sentence.)

Answer (score 3):

The first is simple present. It expresses a condition that currently exists--tasks await you.

The second is simple past. It expresses a condition that began and ended at a specific time in the past--your tasks are done.

The third sentence is the present perfect. It is used to express an action that took place (or a state that existed) at an indefinite time in the past and that still informs the present. It does not mean that you still have a lot of tasks to do--it means that the tasks that you did do are still affecting you, as in

> A: You look tired.
>
> B: I have had a lot of tasks to do this week.

Comment: Don't you think that this may have been answered before (unless it was closed as being too basic for ELU)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first one means that you currently have a lot of tasks. The second one means that you used to have a lot but you completed them. The last one means you have not only had a lot so far this week but that you still have a lot.

The first one is currently have.
The second one is used to have.
The last one is used to have and still have.